# How to secure Grizzly through SSL and basic authentication

Tags: java, ssl, basic-authentication, grizzly

I've got the following code, to get the Grizzly server secured via SSL and additionally using basic authentication:

```
  public static HttpServer getGrizzlyServer(String bindUri, String restClientUri, ResourceConfig rc) throws Exception
  {
    HttpServer result = new HttpServer();
    URL bindURL = null;
    try
    {
      bindURL = new URL(bindUri);
    }
    catch (MalformedURLException e)
    {
      throw e;
    }

    final NetworkListener listener = new NetworkListener("grizzly", bindURL.getHost(), bindURL.getPort());

    result.addListener(listener);
    // do we need SSL?
    listener.setSecure(true);
    SSLEngineConfigurator sslEngineConfigurator = createSSLConfig();
    listener.setSSLEngineConfig(sslEngineConfigurator);
    // Map the path to the processor.
    final ServerConfiguration config = result.getServerConfiguration();
    final HttpHandler handler = ContainerFactory.createContainer(HttpHandler.class, rc);
    config.addHttpHandler(handler, "/");
    result.start();
    return result;
  }

  private static SSLEngineConfigurator createSSLConfig() throws Exception
  {
    final SSLContextConfigurator sslContextConfigurator = new SSLContextConfigurator();
    // override system properties
    File cacerts = new File(
        GrizzlyServerUtil.class.getResource("truststore.ts").getFile());
    if (cacerts.exists())
    {
      sslContextConfigurator.setTrustStoreFile(cacerts.getAbsolutePath());
      sslContextConfigurator.setTrustStorePass("pw");
    }

    // override system properties
    File keystore = new File(
        GrizzlyServerUtil.class.getResource("keystore.jks").getFile());
    if (keystore.exists())
    {
      sslContextConfigurator.setKeyStoreFile(keystore.getAbsolutePath());
      sslContextConfigurator.setKeyStorePass("pw");
    }

    //
    boolean clientMode = false;
    // force client Authentication ...
    boolean needClientAuth = true;
    boolean wantClientAuth = false;
    SSLEngineConfigurator result = new SSLEngineConfigurator(sslContextConfigurator.createSSLContext(), clientMode, needClientAuth,
        wantClientAuth);
    return result;
  }
```

Now my problem is, that if I start the server with the following information:

```
final ResourceConfig rc = new ResourceConfig().packages("ask.dolserveragent");
rc.property("restClientUri", baseRestUri);
rc.register(AuthenticationFilter.class);

try
{
  HttpServer httpServer = GrizzlyServerUtil.getGrizzlyServer(bindUri, baseRestUri, rc);
  return httpServer;
}
catch (Exception e)
{
  e.printStackTrace();
  return null;
}
```

I cannot access the server with https://LOCAL_IP_ADDRESS:1337/application.wadl.
I tried it with and without basic authentication, but the website isn't reachable at all. 
Is there any problem regarding SSL and basic authentication or what did I wrong?